# Using materialTapTargetSize in MaterialButton makes any difference

Tags: flutter

I didn't notice a difference when the `materialTapTargetSize` used or not.
Also there is no difference when the materialTapTargetSize is `padded`.
So how and when does the materialTapTargetSize make the difference?

```
MaterialButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
      ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MaterialTapTargetSize](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialTapTargetSize-class.html) is used to configure size of tap targets like Buttons. It has 2 different values, padded and shrinkWrap. Note that it does not really affect the size of visible buttons but the size of the target which will trigger the button press. ShrinkWrap keeps the size to a minimum while padded increases the size of the tap target to 48px * 48px if it's lesser than that and will have no effect if the size of the button is not lesser than 48px * 48px.

Let's have a look at this example. It's a column with 2 material buttons and 2 radio buttons.

```
Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 100,
        ),
        MaterialButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
          materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text('Button 1'),
          height: 50,
          onPressed: () {
            print('pressed');
          },
        ),
        MaterialButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 20,
          child: Text('Button 2'),
          materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
          onPressed: () {
            print('pressed');
          },
        ),
        Radio(
          value: 1,
          groupValue: 1,
          onChanged: (_) {
            print('1 pressed');
          },
          materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        ),
        Radio(
          value: 1,
          groupValue: 2,
          onChanged: (_) {
            print('2 pressed');
          },
          materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Here both Button 1 and Button 2 are padded but the size of button 1 is 50px * 390px(on my device but the width might vary still it will be larger than 48px) but the height of Button 2 is 20 px. The visible height of button 2 is 20 px only but the tap target height is 48px(which is evident from the empty space between button 1 and button 2). So the vertical empty space around button 2 will also trigger button press for button2.

[image: debug paint off] [image: with debug paint on]

First image shows layout with debug paint off while second image shows the layout with debug paint on. Note the vertical space around button 2, that is the size of tap target for button 2. Also note that there is no extra space around button 1. That's because height of button 1 already exceeds 48 px.

Both Radio buttons look same in size in first image but in second image, it's clear that there is some extra space alongside second radio button. It's because by default size of radio button is 40px * 40 px. Since first radio button has materialTapSize as shrinkWrap, it's tap target size is set to minimum. However since materialTapSize for second radio button is set to padded, it's size is increased to 48px * 48px.